# Show that the function f(x,y) maps the set $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ in a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Show that the function

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
a+b{\tan(x^2+y^2)\over x^2+y^2}  & (x,y) \neq (0,0)
\\a+b & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$$

maps the set  $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ in a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
It would be enough to prove that the function is continuous, but how? Now i know the $$a+b{\tan(x^2+y^2)\over x^2+y^2},  (x,y)\neq(0,0)$$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions, what's left is to find the limit of this expression when (x,y)->(0,0). How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1
$$
and
$$
\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}
$$

Comment: Thanks a bunch i wanna ask you another one if its no trouble?

Comment: $$ a- {bye^x-1 }\over {x} $$ x->0

Comment: a is not in the fraction.

Comment: @BozoVulicevic no problem - is $y$ fixed here?

Comment: y is not fixed , basically same question as above just this function.

Comment: @BozoVulicevic so you're interested in the value of $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{y e^x - 1}{x}$ (since $a$ is just a constant as well as $-b$)?

Answer (score 1):

If you let $u=x^2+y^2$, then

$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}a+b\frac{\tan(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{u\to0}a+b\frac{\tan u}{u}=\lim_{u\to0}a+b\frac{\sin u}{u}\frac{1}{\cos u}=a+b(1)=a+b$.